# Ubuntu 18.04 VPN cannot ping window samba host-names but can resolve via IP

Tags: 18.04, vpn, ping, pptp, pptpd

I am currently running ubuntu 18.04 box and I have configured pptpd to run a PPTP VPN server.

I have followed this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPTPServer

I’ve tried configuring the server using:
ROUTING CHECKLIST – PROXYARP
And 
ROUTING CHECKLIST – FORWARDING
Which was described in the notes here:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/pptpd.conf.5.html

In both configurations, I can ping other machines on the network using IP but not hostname when connected to the ubuntu PPTP server.

If I am on a local machine, I can ping clients using both hostnames and IPs.  It just on the client machine (window 10) when connected to ubuntu PPTP server I can’t ping using hostname.
My remote network is on 192.168.1.1-200 and the VPN client is on 192.168.0.100

After hours of googling, I have hit a dead-end of knowledge!